# Animation wait in xml my solution from program isn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

Hello I have anim xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="2.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    />
```

when I click on button imagelayout come up from bottom. duration 300ms

And I need after 300 ms add 1000ms for only standing layout and after be invisible..

I try solve this problem with thise code:

```
ImageView delpop= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletepop);
    delpop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation animdel;
    animdel = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.popdelanim);
    FrameLayout ppdl= (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.popupDelete);
    ppdl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ppdl.startAnimation(animdel);
    animdel.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            ImageView delpop= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletepop);
            delpop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            final ImageView delpop= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletepop);
            // popupdel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            delpop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    delpop.setAlpha(1f);
                    delpop.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(300);
                    if (clicked) {
                        PomocnaDel(DEL);
                    }
                    DEL=-1;

                }
            }, 1000);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


        }
    });
```

thise code run good, but only one. I call this method ↑ for 6 different buttons. 
Work good for every one, but only once. If I click on first button code run good, but after when I click on 2nd button animation not work.

If I click on only one button everything good, but if after it click on button too not work good.

Please Help

Thanks

/////////////////////////////////edit///////////////////////////////////////////

Ithing so when i start animation twice isnt run from start (no restart). it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FADE animation on end method, but fade animation remained on 0f =>j transparrent.

I solve it with thise code in onAnimationStar
delpop.setAlpha(1f);